# What does the phrase "ride every wall" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from a drift race game's description:

> If you can control your car’s tune, that’s when you can think about
>   throwing it in hard and start **riding every wall** you see.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase **riding every wall** here. Also, it would be great if you share your opinion on the clarity of the sentence. Is the message clear here?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence clarity is weak given the slang used in the sentence "If you can control your car’s tune [engine tuning], that’s when you can think about throwing it in hard [that's when you can consider doing the more extreme stunts] and start riding every wall you see." Wall riding is a racing technique as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjwYcFwUxi8).